# CS61A PYTHON3 OK:KeyError: 'BREAK_LOOP'

Tags: python-3.x

I don't know what to do with it.Im in a hurry.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTvJg.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4YMQ.jpg)

Comment: I am working on an Indian licence plate model with Python. I am getting totally wrong characters from the licence plate. For example, licence plate number : PB10EB2640 after character recognition :

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem:**
It would be helpful if you could show the code, but based on the error given, it looks like you are trying to get the value from a dictionary using a key that doesn't exist.

**How To Fix:** You can fix your problem by:

- There might have been a typo. Did you mean a different key-value pair? Perhaps you were referring to a different dictionary?
- Another possibility is that the key wasn't added to the dictionary. Make sure that you create and add all values to the dictionary before you query it!

Comment: The following answer is very useful to me. I don't know how to reply to him for the first time. Thank you for solving the problem that wasted me about 6 hours. I will replace the file with the latest version of the course and it will run normally